# What does ECHO .> mean in batch file?

Tags: batch-file, dos

I have a batch file with the following code within:

```
ECHO .> C:\file.txt
```

I read about ECHO and understand what it is used for, but what I do not know is what are the characters used for after the word echo (`.>`) and what is the use of the path of file after that.

Comment: The answers below are correct, but I've never used a period to overwrite a file as the first line in a file probably shouldn't be a period. BUT I user echo. all the time to create a new line in the command window/prompt. It's good for formatting

Comment: @SpectralGhost: yes. `echo.` writes an empty line. Redirect it to a file, and you get an empty file (containing `<CR><LF>` ("empty line") to be exact). I think, the space between `echo` and `.` in the question is a transcription error, as a single dot usually makes no sense in a file.

Comment: yeah, I've used it to create newlines in my scripts before. But, I was taking the asker's word on the exact text :)

Comment: Note that pure "new line" requires `echo.` without space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`>` redirects the output of the command before.

`echo .>c:\file.txt`prints a dot to the file `c:\file.txt`, overwriting its contents (so it will contain a dot only afterwards)

I think, you got it wrong. Usually `echo.>file.txt` is used to create a empty file (or delete the contents, if the file exists). (Note the missing space)

Answer (score 5):

It's used to truncate, or create if necessary, the file.  `echo .` outputs a single line which is redirected to the file, effectively truncating it.
To obtain an absolutely empty file I often use `cd . > filename`. I don't know where I picked that one up but it's been around for a long time on UNIX systems.

Comment: Very true. Updated the answer (yes after a year and a half) :)